# How to identify the warning generated instances of an operation in a loop?

Tags: r, debugging, warnings, sapply, chi-squared

Based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24359874/4836511), I have formulated the below code to perform `chisq.test` for 33 variables.

```
sapply(Indices,function(i){
  chisq.test(data.cleaned[,i],data.cleaned$Out)$p.value })
```

This code produces 9 warnings, hopefully due to the violation of the assumptions made for `chisq.test`. I would like to identify for which instances of `i` the warnings are issued ?

I assume that there is no need of a reproducible example for this simple question from a beginner.

Comment: Try putting `print(i)` into a function. I am not sure if the warnings are printed after loop or on each iteration. but you can try

Answer (score 1):

I generate this example to reproduce the problem:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rep(c("a","b"), 22))

options(warn=1)

sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){
  df[i,"x"] <- letters[round(rnorm(1,mean=2, sd = .5),0)]
  print (i)
})
```

with `options(warn=1)` warning is printed when it occurs. (from [Andrie answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211718/how-to-print-warning-messages-as-they-occur))
And `print(i)` tells me on which iteration it is produced.

Comment: Thanks for the simplest possible answer. I was wondering if any way possible to only print `i` values when there is a warning. As I have only 33 iterations, it's not a big deal to check. When there are huge number of iterations, say 1000+, it will be a tidy task to know warning issuing `i`'s.

Comment: I'll try to find it out

Comment: Yeah, all the solution I have found is related with `tryCatch` function. I think Roland's answer is more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tryCatch` and return warning messages from your anonymous function together with the `chisq.test` result in a `list`.

Example:

```
fun <- function(x) {
  if (x == 2) warning("It's a two!")
  return(x^2)
}
lapply(1:3, function(i) tryCatch(list(result = fun(i), warning = "no warning"),
                                 warning = function(w) list(result = fun(i), 
                                                            warning = as.character(w))))

#[[1]]
#[[1]]$result
#[1] 1
#
#[[1]]$warning
#[1] "no warning"
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$result
#[1] 4
#
#[[2]]$warning
#[1] "simpleWarning in fun(i): It's a two!\n"
#
#
#[[3]]
#[[3]]$result
#[1] 9
#
#[[3]]$warning
#[1] "no warning"
#
#
#Warning message:
#In fun(i) : It's a two!
```

Comment: Thanks for the quite contraceptive answer. I will understand it and use for my requirement.